# Pre-decrement operator in JavaScript while loop causes stack overflow

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, infinite-loop

Recently I was going through some JavaScript code and at multiple places they are using a while loop to iterate over arrays. The way they do it is as

```
var i = dataArray.length;
while ( i-- ) {
   // iterating over the array.
}
```

We know that the post-decrement operator here would first supply the value to while call and then will reduce it by one. So in this case for the first iteration if the array length is 10, the while call checks for i to be 10 and we get the value of i inside the loop to be 9. This continues till i reaches a value of 0 and then we exit out of loop. Precisely speaking we are iterating the array in a reverse manner.

This is fine. Where it really confuses me is when I write a pre-decrement operator, the while loop runs forever resulting in a stack overflow.

```
var i = dataArray.length;
while ( --i ){
   // This loop would run forever.
}
```

Why is this happening? Won't doing `--i` will also result into `i` hitting the 0 value at some point of time and breaking the loop?

Comment: If array is empty, its value would be 0 at first, and `--i` gives `-1`, which will be evaluated to true, so it never stop.

Comment: `So in this case for the first iteration if the array length is 10,` If so, what are you doing in `while` loop? Is `i` what you are expecting in `while` loop context? Anyway, you have to provide MCVE

Comment: Don't iterate arrays with while loops. Indices add complexity - if you just want to iterate an array it's as simple as `for(var item of array){ /* work on item */ }` or in older browsers `array.forEach(function(item){ /* work on item */ }`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - both of those also significantly slower on large arrays.

Comment: @Stephen if you're using a large array you'd want a typed array anyway. Also, decrementing an array and "going back" isn't faster - it's cargo culting. Iterating an array with `while` in JavaScript is cargo culting - because some algorithms benefit from it (like algorithms that remove elements that are better off shifting a smaller portion of the array) people started writing it everywhere - as if a JIT compiler can't figure out how to optimize a `>= x` call to a `JNZ` instruction. __If__ (and that's a big if) `for... of` is currently slow in current compilers - that'll change soon.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I can't comment on typed arrays. However, I'm just pointing out what's fact right now - for/of and forEach are very, very slow to process even in modern browsers, so they should be used with care. The 'while' that the OP has pointed out is fast, but feels and looks sloppy, so I'd never use it considering it has almost zero gain over a standard for(i; i<x; i++) which is programmer friendly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only the case if `dataArray` is empty. In that casen `i = dataArray.length` becomes zero. Then when you enter the while loop, `i` is pre-decremented to `-1`. Since all non-zero numbers evaluate to `true`, the loop keeps on going forever.

However, if the array has any elements, this will not happend and the loop will terminate. This code will illustrate the effect without craching anything:

```
function loop(x) {
   var i = x.length;
   while ( --i ) {
       console.log(i);
       if(i == -5) break; //Break after a while so we avoid an endless loop.
   }
}

loop([]);
loop([1,1,1]);
```

The output of the first call is `-1, -2, -3, -4, -5`, and the output of the second call is `2, 1`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/570wg6o0/).

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way of writing `While` loop.

```
while(condition){
    // Your code
    // iterator update (i++/i--)
}
```

Why you loop stops? JavaScript considers `0` as false and stops when reaches 0.

Also can't tell why predecrement runs forever. This might be because `i` never reaches 0;

#### Loop simulation

```js
var data = [];

function createArray(){
 for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
     data.push(i);
    }
}

function preDecrementLoop(){
    var i = data.length;
    while(--i){
     console.log(i);
    }
}

function postDecrementLoop(){
    var i = data.length;
    while(i--){
     console.log(i);
    }
}

(function(){
    createArray();
    console.log("pre decrement");
    preDecrementLoop();
    console.log("post decrement");
    postDecrementLoop();
})()
```

Note: `--i` will skip loop for `0` since 0 is considered as false, `while (0) == while (false)`.

Comment: i-- does, `--i` will skip last element since `while(0)` means false. Also I would suggest using a `forEach`

Comment: Sorry typo, i meant `--i`